# Getting "No such property: getResponseCode for class: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection" when the app is running

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

This is bit wired as "sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection" class is already extending java.net.HttpURLConnection abstract class which has the getResponseCode() public method. App is running locally and hosted test environments but not in client's live. Since it's live dont have much access to. Any clue or anyone else experienced the same?

Comment: A trace would be useful. But error message says *property* NOT *method*.

Comment: It would do that if youleft off the brackets on the method call

Comment: I should have said it *might* do that

Comment: @g00se as i have said cannot go for a new build that prints the stack trace, but same is working in local and tests. would that be tomcat version issue?

Comment: I wouldn't like to speculate without seeing the real evidence